# paypal - monthly subscribe with custom payement in first month

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing, nvp

I am creating a web platform where users must subscribe to use its modules, each module must be purchased every month to use it. what i want to do is enabling a recurring payment each month.I know I can make monthly recurring payments and Paypal charges a sum each month, but what  if a user subscribe in the middle of a month (like 15-06-2016). i must charge him only with remaining 15 days of June(because he will use it only in half of a month), then Paypal do the job each 1th of the next month( July-August.. etc). so How can i procede to 
 - charge the user for using a module in the remaining days of the current month
 - make recurring payment each 1th of the next month.

I'm using nvp api of paypal.

I hope I was clear.

Comment: If a user suscribe in the middle of a month, he will be charged in the middle of the next month.

Comment: Would be easier to simply bill them monthly from when they subscribe.

Comment: Although this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957228/paypal-monthly-subscription-plan-settings-for-first-day-of-the-month-django-py/50018563#50018563 refers to a Python implementation, the Paypal API usage remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may build a logic on your site to  charge only the difference amount and setup PayPal Reference Transactions, PayPal RT allows you to charge buyers a variable amount at different intervals.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

Comment: SOLVED, thank you very much but i willl just charge the user  with an initial amount by adding  INITAMT field to the request   with the exact calculated value then the profile start date is in the 1th day of each month as i wished.
thanx to this useful link:
 https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-recurring-payments-reference-transactions-and-preapproved-payments/